# How to count multiple values from one column using SQL Server CASE keyword?

Tags: sql, case

I want to display a result like this:

My data for each column is as follows:

```
CustomerID  FirstName   Total_Count_Status ResultMessage
  1          Noor        10                Completed Calls
  2          ALi          6                InProgress Calls
  3          Jhon         9                CallBack  Calls
  4          Maaan        1                MoneyCall Calls
  5          samuel       5                Cancelled Calls 
  6          Khan         3                Dispatched Calls
```

In my workorder table I have the `OrderStatusID` column data:

```
OrderStatusID
3
2
3
5
7
```

I have the following Hardcoded values for my Case:

```
for Pending = 0,
for Dispatched = 1,
    InProgress = 2,
    Complete = 3,
    Estimate = 4,
    CallBack = 5,
    MoneyCall = 6,
    Cancelled = 7,
```

This will be used for show up their status.

i have my table name : WorkOrder which has column OrderStatusID  i want to count OrderstatusID for each

if OrderStatusID='3' we should have to count all 3 values of orderstatusID column and display result like in the above table .
same is for other ..values

How i can create Proc for situation like this ??Thanks

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi - you've tagged this stata. Are you definitely using Stata and not some other database? You should probably tag this 'sql' and your database instead.

Comment: Regardless of whether or not this is a question related to Stata, it's really, *really* hard to tell what you're asking here.  I've tried to clean up the formatting, but I couldn't even try to clean up the grammar because I can't figure out what's actually being asked...

Comment: What do you mean by "not ok"?  Are there any error messages?  Was there unexpected output (and if so, what)?

Comment: And...now your question is even more illegible.  Please start over from the beginning and coherently explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Part of the syntax is:

```
 CASE WHEN <condition> THEN <expression> ELSE <expression> END
```

The trick is to convert counts into sums and to evaluate the expressions as 0 or 1:

```
SELECT ...,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN OrderStatusID = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS CompletedCalls,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN OrderStatusID = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS InProgressCalls,
       ...
```

You'll need your FROM, WHERE, and GROUP BY clauses as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have solved my problem: thanks for your answers.

Here is my refined query:

```
**@DateFrom datetime,                  
@dateTo datetime                 
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT OFF  

SELECT @DateFrom as DateFrom, @dateTo as DateTo, SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalCompleted,0)) as TotalCompleted,SUM(ISNULL(TotalMoneyCall,0)) as TotalMoneyCall ,  
SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalDispatched,0)) as TotalDispatched, SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalInProgress,0)) as TotalInProgress,  
SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalEstimate,0)) as TotalEstimate,  SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalCancelled,0)) as TotalCancelled,  
SUM(ISNULL(myTable.TotalPending,0)) as TotalPending  FROM   
(  
SELECT @DateFrom as DateFrom, @dateTo as DateTo,
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=3 then   count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalCompleted,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=6 then   count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalMoneyCall,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=1 then count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalDispatched,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=2 then count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalInProgress,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=4 then count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalEstimate,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=7 then count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalCancelled,  
CASE WHEN ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)=0 then count(ISNULL(OrderStatusID,0)) end  as TotalPending 
From WorkOrder  where  CreatedOn  between @DateFrom AND  @dateTo group by OrderStatusID, CreatedOn) AS myTable**
```